# Why is the Content not aligned in the middle?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

The Code attached consists of an animation CSS box with a `<p>`. It's working but the problem is that, why is it not vertical aligned? I will need to use flex function: "align-items = center" to make it aligned.

```css
.LoaderBox {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.00);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.LoaderBox>p {
  color: rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.00);
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.LoaderBox_spinner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  display: block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="LoaderBox">
  <div class="LoaderBox_spinner"></div>
  <p>Verifying</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The default value for `align-items` is `stretch`, which mean the element will take the whole height of the flex container. Here, you have set the `height` of the spinner manually, so the `stretch` is overwritten and it seems to behave like a `flex-start`. The best solution is to use `align-items: center` to fix this.

Comment: I still don't understand the reason behind. Both the "box" and "<p>" is not appear to be the same alignment. Look at the "<p>", it suppose to be on top in the <div class="LoaderBox">, but instead its vertical aligned...so why is it so? This is why I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `align-items: center` to your flex-container `.LoaderBox`.

By default all items are stretched ([`align-items: stretch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)).

`p` has equal vertical margins by default (`margin-top` and `margin-bottom`), and `div` doesn't. So in this case `p` determines flex-container's height. And also looks like it's centered vertically.

Demo:

```css
.LoaderBox {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.00);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* new */
  justify-content: center;
}

.LoaderBox>p {
  color: rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.00);
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.LoaderBox_spinner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  display: block;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
  }
}

@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="LoaderBox">
  <div class="LoaderBox_spinner"></div>
  <p>Verifying</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, thanks for the advice. I already know how to make it vertical aligned. But what I don't understand is why the <p> doesn't require vertical aligned by default and it's appear vertical aligned. If by default "align-items" is stretched, then the <p> should be appear in the top in the <div class="LoaderBox">....isnt it..?

Comment: @BSS `p` has vertical `margin`s by default (`top` and `bottom`), and `div` doesn't. So in this case `p` looks higher.

Comment: @BSS Can you please accept answer if it fit your needs or leave a comment if you need something else?

Comment: Based on what you said, I think I understand and get the answer now. So I did a little verification. If <p> has default top-bottom-margin that make it vertical aligned, then by applying the same thing to the spinner box, the spinner box should also be vertical aligned. Therefore, I have add the **top-margin:auto**, **bottom-margin:auto** for the spinner box. And it work.!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BSS It's up to you, but I would recommend to set `align-items` for flex-container than adding `margin-top: auto` and `margin-bottom: auto` for every flex item you want to center. I think this will look much clearer and will be more maintainable and flexible. Also there are option to use `align-self: center` which is also much more descriptive.

Comment: You are right and I agreed with what you said. Setting to much individual margin setting to each container really is not the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.LoaderBox {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.00);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
 padding:20px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  
  .LoaderBox>p {
    color: rgba(106, 106, 106, 1.00);
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
 margin-left:20px;
  }
  
  .LoaderBox_spinner {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: #333;
    -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
    display: block;
 float:left;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
    0% {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
    }
    50% {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
    }
    100% {
      -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes sk-rotateplane {
    0% {
      transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
      -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    50% {
      transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
      -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
    }
    100% {
      transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
      -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    }
  }
  
  p{ float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="LoaderBox">
    <div class="LoaderBox_spinner"></div>
    <p>Verifying</p>

  </div>
```

Comment: I don't think the is the answer I am seeking. I already got the answer how to solve my problem. What I want is to understand is why the <p> appear to be vertical aligned with "align-items:center". But for the spinner box, it require to have the "align-items:center". Thanks .